# Disable 'RuntimeIdentifier' subfolder in ASP.NET Core output path

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

ASP.NET Core projects create *many* subdirectories like:

> ```
> bin\Debug\ne47\win81-x64
> ```

I found that one of them can be disabled with the *secret* `AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` and I now have:

> ```
> bin\Debug\win81-x64
> ```

but I'd like it to just be the old

> ```
> bin\Debug
> ```

so I tried to find something similar in [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com) but there is not even the first option.

Why is this so secret that it's nowhere documented? Is there such an option for the other subdirectory too?

I guess this is comming from the

> ```
> <RuntimeIdentifier>win81-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
> ```

but why? I didn't ask for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Disable 'RuntimeIdentifier' subfolder in ASP.NET Core output path

You can disable this behavior by setting:

```
<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
```

This behavior comes from the [.NET Core RID Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this comming :-o This is cheating ;-] How did you know about it? I mean that you just have to combine the `AppendSomethingToOutputPath` with the other element? Where is this documented?

Comment: Yes, it is rarely noticed, I know it from an issue on github https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/512#issuecomment-332291043 when I investigate the output path for .NET Standard project.